# Node JS, how to use http.request POST into external var?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to return the result of a HTTP.request result outside the request.

Here is my code :

```
function repromptFunction() {
    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
        host: 'api.domain.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/path/file.json',
        method: 'POST'
    };

    http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            var recv = JSON.parse(data);
            var repromptText = recv.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[0].fcttext_metric;
            return repromptText;
        });
    }).end();
}

console.log('final value is ' + repromptFunction());
```

But each time, the console.log return undefined. I understand that the code is executed in an asynchronous way.

What should I do to be sure to receive anything but not this undefined result to my Console.log ?

Comment: You need to use Promise because request is async

Answer (score 0):

Your `return repromptText` is returning from the anonymous function that was passed to `http.request`.  The `repromptText()` function doesn't return anything here.  You would need to put your `console.log` into the end callback and/or have that callback trigger the work you wish to do.